# "Invalid Texture For Sprite" Cocos2d Tilemap Error

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tile

I am trying to make a game in Cocos2d that uses an orthogonal tilemap. I create the map in tiled using a simple tileset I drew in Adobe Illustrator. The tiles are 32x32 pixels, and the map is only 20x20 tiles. When I use the tilemap in Cocos2d, it works fine when I test it out on the iPhone simulator. However, when I test it on my iPod touch, the app crashes (terminates with NSException) and it gives me an error saying

-(id) initWithTexture:(CCTexture2D*)texture

{

```
NSAssert(texture!=nil, @"Invalid texture for sprite");
CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
rect.size = texture.contentSize;
return [self initWithTexture:texture rect:rect];
```

}

I've messed with the map and the tiles but I cannot get the app to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does the NSException say? "Invalid texture for sprite?" It'll be above the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The thing was that I have not added tileset image to my project. When the app was compiled, this resource has not been copied to the device, so texture could not been loaded. I have simply added image for the tileset and it worked ok. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this - but it could be you have not got the case of the filename correct. If you have a file called `image.PNG` but you reference it as `@"image.png"` it will work in the simulator, but not when deployed to the device.

I learnt this from [this book](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/).

Comment: I just checked my code and made sure the filename was written correctly. I tried running it again on my iPod, but the same error came up. Thanks for the idea anyway. -skiboi38